# Can't find resource bundle

Tags: java, resourcebundle, properties-file, netbeans-8, missingmethodexception

I'm trying to load a properties files, but i keep getting this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't
>   find bundle for base name D:\bdtej04694\Mis
>   documentos\NetBeansProjects\SMS_Clientes_Menores\dist\lib\help.properties,
>   locale es_VE  at
>   java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:1499)
>     at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1322)
>     at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:721)

I'm trying to making this

```
    private static PropertyResourceBundle slInfo = null;
    //and in another method i'm doing this
    String directory = System.getProperty("user.dir");
            slInfo = (PropertyResourceBundle)ResourceBundle.getBundle(directory+"\\dist\\lib\\help.properties"); 
//I put it on a different folder, just in case i want to make changes in the connection strings inside the properties files, without build the project again in netbeans
```

I searched on the web (and obviously, in this page), but i can't find an aswer to fit my problem

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

its seems you have problem with path of you properties file

```
D:\bdtej04694\Mis documentos\NetBeansProjects\SMS_Clientes_Menores\dist\lib\help.properties
```

try to avoid space in path of properties file, you have one here **Mis documentos**

regarding you comment :

change your path like below

```
String tempPath =  directory+"\\dist\\lib\\help.properties";
String finalPath = tempPath.replace("\\", "/");
```

and use this finalPath

Comment: Yes @p27 , but if you see, i get the value of the path with the second instruction, so i don't define the path "by hand", so the path is obtained automatically

Comment: try to replace \ with / at you final path. like below : D:/bdtej04694/Mis documentos/NetBeansProjects/SMS_Clientes_Menores/dist/lib/help.properties